# IHttpContextAccessor in ActionFilterAttribute Identity.Name is Null

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, identity, authorize

I have setup a `AuthorizationFilter` on Api controller action, during the first call the User Identity is being set but while accessing the httpContextAccessor in subsequent api requests the User.Identity.Name is null.

I have tried to use injection with setting up the HttpContextAccessor as singleton.

AuthorizationFilter code :

```
IIdentity identity = _singleSignOnUserService.GetUser(userInfo);
                        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
```

Startup.cs Injection code :

```
services.AddScoped<AuthAttribute>();
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Controller code :

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
TesController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
   _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}
```

Why would `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` be null even though the AuthorizeFilter has set the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by setting Authorization token in header of client requests to Webapi , it turned out the problem was because of the fact that client application - Angular and Core Webapi are hosted on different domains.